# Stuck reading Xml with xmlpullparser

Tags: android, xml

i'm a newbie at programming and to better improve my understanding of parsing xml in android, i'm trying to fetch some data from a webservice about earthquakes. I've read all the related topics here on Stackoverflow and different tutorials, but there's something wrong in my code.
Here's an excerpt from the Xml i want to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII" standalone="yes"?>
<q:quakeml xmlns:q="http://quakeml.org/xmlns/quakeml/1.2" xmlns="http://quakeml.org/xmlns/bed/1.2" xmlns:ingv="http://webservices.ingv.it/fdsnws/event/1">
    <eventParameters publicID="smi:webservices.ingv.it/fdsnws/event/1/query">    
        <event publicID="smi:webservices.ingv.it/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventId=16736781">      
            <type>earthquake</type>      
            <description>        
                <type>region name</type>        
                <text>Tirreno Meridionale (MARE)</text>      
            </description>      
            <preferredMagnitudeID>smi:webservices.ingv.it/fdsnws/event/1/query?magnitudeId=49992691</preferredMagnitudeID>      
            <preferredOriginID>smi:webservices.ingv.it/fdsnws/event/1/query?originId=49089691</preferredOriginID>      
            <creationInfo>        
                <agencyID>INGV</agencyID>        
                <author>SURVEY-INGV</author>        
                <creationTime>2017-08-16T14:59:48</creationTime>      
            </creationInfo>
```

And the following is the portion of code i wrote:

```
private static List<Earthquake> extractFeatureFromQuakeml(String earthquakeXML) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

    XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    xmlFactoryObject.setNamespaceAware(true);
    XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();

    myparser.setInput(new StringReader(earthquakeXML));

    // If the JSON string is empty or null, then return early.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(earthquakeXML)) {
        return null;
    }

    // Create an empty ArrayList that we can start adding earthquakes to
    List<Earthquake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        int eventType = myparser.getEventType();
        Log.d("Step", "Started parsing");

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String location = "";
            String time = "";
            double magnitude = 0.0;
            String url = "";
            String tag = myparser.getName();
            String text = "";

            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    //Log.d("Step","Started parsing, end tag: " + tag);
                    if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("event")) {
                        url = myparser.getAttributeValue(null, "publicID");
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Url" + url);
                        myparser.next();
                    }

                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    text = myparser.getText();
                    if (text != null) {
                        if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("type") && text.equalsIgnoreCase("region name")) {
                            myparser.nextText();
                            location = "" + myparser.getText();
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Location" + location);
                        }
                    }

                    if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("creationTime")) {
                        time = "" + myparser.getText();
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Time" + time);
                    }

                    if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("mag")) {
                        myparser.next();
                        myparser.next();
                        String smagnitude = myparser.getText();
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Magnitude" + smagnitude);
                    }

                    if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("creationTime")) {
                        time = "" + myparser.getText();
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Time" + time);
                    }

                    if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("mag")) {
                        myparser.next();
                        myparser.next();
                        String smagnitude = myparser.getText();
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Magnitude" + smagnitude);
                    }

                    break;
            }

            // Create a new {@link Earthquake} object with the magnitude, location, time,
            // and url from the JSON response.
            if (location != null && magnitude != 0.0 && time != null && url != null) {
                Earthquake earthquake = new Earthquake(magnitude, location, time, url);
                // Add the new {@link Earthquake} to the list of earthquakes.
                earthquakes.add(earthquake);
            }

            eventType = myparser.next();
        }

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

        Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the earthquake XML results", e);
    }

    // Return the list of earthquakes
    return earthquakes;
}
```

Now the only value i get is the url, other variables are always null. 
Can someone point out the flaws in my code? And please be gentle, i've started coding just 3 weeks ago :)

Thank you so much!

Comment: Rather than using XmlPullParserFactory and XmlPullParser. You can use Retrofit library using XML converter. Please integrate retrofit and follow https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-how-to-integrate-xml-converter

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is you are making empty every time in your while loop and you should understand that while loop will get call multiple time( Example when you get the Url and store that value in `url`, and you are calling `myparser.next();` so it will get the next element `type` and it will come inside while loop now you are removing every value, you are removing `url` value too.).

Instead you can creates an `Earthquake` object when get start tag as `event` and every end tag you can add the coressponding value in that `Earthquake` object and at the end tag of `event`, add the `Earthquake` object to the list.

I modified your code little how to do that, you can set all remaining values

```
private static List<Earthquake> extractFeatureFromQuakeml(String earthquakeXML) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

    XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    xmlFactoryObject.setNamespaceAware(true);
    XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();

    myparser.setInput(new StringReader(earthquakeXML));

    // If the JSON string is empty or null, then return early.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(earthquakeXML)) {
        return null;
    }

    // Create an empty ArrayList that we can start adding earthquakes to
    List<Earthquake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        int eventType = myparser.getEventType();
        Log.d("Step", "Started parsing");

        Earthquake earthquake = null;

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            // String location = "";
            // String time = "";
            // double magnitude = 0.0;
            // String url = "";
            String tag = myparser.getName();
            String text = "";

            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    //Log.d("Step","Started parsing, end tag: " + tag);
                    if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("event")) {
                        url = myparser.getAttributeValue(null, "publicID");
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Url" + url);
                        myparser.next();

                        // We are creating Earthquake here
                        earthquake = new Earthquake(); 

                        earthquake.setUrl(url);
                    }

                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    text = myparser.getText();
                    if (text != null) {
                        if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("type") && text.equalsIgnoreCase("region name")) {
                            myparser.nextText();
                            earthquake.setLocation(myparser.getText());
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Location" + earthquake.getLocation());
                        }
                    }

                    if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("creationTime")) {
                        earthquake.setTime(myparser.getText());
                        // time = "" + myparser.getText();
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Time" + earthquake.getTime());
                    }

                    if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("mag")) {
                        myparser.next();
                        myparser.next();
                        earthquake.setMagnitude(myparser.getText());
                        // String smagnitude = myparser.getText();
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Magnitude" + earthquake.getMagnitude());
                    }

                    if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("event")) {
                        earthquakes.add(earthquake);
                    }

                    break;
            }
            eventType = myparser.next();
        }

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

        Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the earthquake XML results", e);
    }

    // Return the list of earthquakes
    return earthquakes;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I knew the logic behind my code was wrong, your's has much more sense :D Still, even after changing the code to your suggestions, reading the log i get only null values, except for the url, maybe i'm using the xmlpullparser's method incorrectly.. the thing that piss me off is that the getAttributeValue() method return something, while getText() is always null. But tank you again for helping a stranger understanding the basics of reading xmls :D

Comment: @Hrothgah, Could you update your latest code in your question..?

Comment: starting from your suggestion I managed to solve the problem.
I've made a wrong assumption as how the parser.next() method work, I thought that when the "cursor" is on a starting tag, 
you could read the text simply calling the parser.getText() method; instead I had to move one step further to position the cursor just on the text element to read it.
Also, but I don't know if it's something peculiar to this particular xml, after a closing tag, the next() method return a text ("/n    "), so obviously when calling the getName() the method return null.

Comment: I dont know the "best practices" for StackOverflow, should I update my question with the solution, to better help someone with my same problem? Anyway, again thank you for you kindness :D